# My sharepoint online site collection is showing 2% usage with only 4 pages added

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, storage

I am working on a new sharepoint online office 365. and i have create a new enterprise wiki site collection. then inside the new site collection i added 4 wiki pages (simple pages containing text and tables). now i checked the admin site for our sharepoint online and i find that the percentage usage for our new site collection is 2% !!. as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce on the following 3 questions:-

1. now seems my current setting (default) is not reliable, as on the first day i am consuming 2% of the site collection storage. so can i increase the site collection storage ?
2. now when i create the site collection, i was not asked how many storage i want to have for my new site collection... while i was asked to specify the "Server Resource Quota" which i leave it with the defualt value 300. so i am not sure is the "Server Resource Quota" related to the allocated storage for the site collections ?
3. can i increase/decrease the values assigned to the "Server Resource Quota" & the allocated storage for my site collections?? or these 2 values can not be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got to think there's a baseline storage amount that comes with a fresh site collection - even though it sometimes shows as zero.  If you're at 28% after adding 40 wiki pages, maybe you've got something to ask about.

"Server Resource Quota" refers to the usage metrics for sandbox code. And since sandbox code is now disallowed in SPO, that metric is absolutely meaningless and has no business in the UI anymore.

I'm not aware of a way to set the defaults, but if you create sites programmatically you can specify values for both. I always set Server Resource Quota to zero.

Comment: yes i read that Server Resource Quota is used to prevent hacking/breaking the site collection due to sandbox code. but we can not have sandbox code inside office 365! so i agree with you that this value is meaningless,, but at-least the server quote can be changed using the UI. but my question is about the "Percentage used".. now let assume your assumption is valid; that i added 50 wiki pages and the percentage used was increased to 30%.. this mean i need to increase something... so which value i need to increase to minimize the percentage usage?? thnx

Comment: can you adivce on my above comment if you can .. thanks

Comment: You can adjust the storage quota on a per-site level from the admin page or via PowerShell. Select the site in the admin UI and the Storage Quota button will light up on the ribbon.